# Strange Path when compile qt app for qnx

Tags: qt

I try to compile my app, QNX and Qt is all set. 
in line 3. 
C:/QNX650/target/qnx6armle-v7 is in the QNX_TARGET env var, and C:/QNX650/host/win32/x86 is QNX_HOST env var. this is strange they combine together.

### Qtcreator, debug mode.this is the only output

```
qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -c -Wno-psabi -lang-c++ -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_CLIPBOARD -DHMI_PLUGIN_DEBUG -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../../QtQNX/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/qnx_armv7le/mkspecs/qnx-armv7le-qcc -I../MQueue_Demo -I../MQueue_Demo/qtquick2applicationviewer -I../MQueue_Demo/depends/MQueue/include -I../MQueue_Demo/depends/MQueue/include/native -I../MQueue_Demo/depends/hmi_interfaces -I../../../../QtQNX/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/qnx_armv7le/include -I../../../../QtQNX/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/qnx_armv7le/include/QtQuick -I../../../../QtQNX/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/qnx_armv7le/include/QtQml -I../../../../QtQNX/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/qnx_armv7le/include/QtNetwork -I../../../../QtQNX/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/qnx_armv7le/include/QtGui -I../../../../QtQNX/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/qnx_armv7le/include/QtGui/5.0.2 -I../../../../QtQNX/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/qnx_armv7le/include/QtGui/5.0.2/QtGui -I../../../../QtQNX/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/qnx_armv7le/include/QtCore -I. -IC:\QNX650\target\qnx6\armle-v7/target/qnx6/usr/include -IC:\QNX650\target\qnx6\armle-v7/target/qnx6/usr/include/freetype2 -I. -o main.obj ../MQueue_Demo/main.cpp
cc: unknown target 'gcc_ntoarmv7le+debug'
cc: no targets defined in C:/QNX650/target/qnx6/armle-v7/host/win32/x86/etc/qcc!
make: *** [main.obj] Error 1
09:46:25: The process "C:\QNX650\host\win32\x86\usr\bin\make.exe" exited with code 2.
```

Comment: Is this from Qt creator or command line? Does it build in release mode?

Comment: What is your application code, and how do you try to build it? Please paste more error output than just this. Are you using cmake, qmake, or something else or building?

Comment: Qtcreator, debug mode.this is the only output.

Comment: Are you also getting issues in release mode? Have you tried to obtain more information on the command line? Is your application built by qmake, cmake, or something else?

Comment: nope, install by binary from qt.